# how to protect wso2 api manager login page from XSS attack?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I used onmouseover=alert("") in ui segment of login page wso2 and we cant login anymore and this is a type of xss attack. what is the solution friends and how we cant prevent attacks like this?

[image: XSS attack]

Answer (score 1):

The process is documented in the official WSO2 API Manager documentation. You can check it [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/administer/product-security/mitigating-cross-site-scripting-attacks/#!)

Comment: this configuration doesn't work on api manager 3.2.0 @usuario